# How to find P_Value (i.e. *) in Fit Regression Model and Pool standard deviation S (i.e. *) In Minitab17?

Tags: statistics, minitab, minitab-16

S;    R-sq ; R-sq(adj)  ;R-sq(pred)

* ; 100.00%  ;        *    ;       *

Coefficients

Term        ;            Coef;  Coef ; T-Value;  P-Value ;    VIF

Constant         ;     0.07526   ;  *    ;    *;        *;

Hardware EV      ;       0.3593   ;  *   ;     *  ;      *;  230.84

Mechanical EV    ;       0.2933 ;    *  ;      *;        *  ; 75.04

Production EV    ;       0.1455  ;   *   ;     * ;       * ; 252.27

Firmware EV      ;      -0.3805 ;    *  ;      *   ;     * ;  38.53

> Note> i need the values in the place of *.

Comment: Cleaning/formatting your question will maximize your chance to get an answer.

Comment: You should say what these partial results came from. It looks like a linear regression. If so, the large VIF values suggest colinearity among the predictors which may make the solution ill-defined, inhibiting calculation of standard errors and consequently t- and p- values. We're there any warning messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are insufficient degrees of freedom for the calculations (including the standard deviation and the model term p-values).  If this is from a DOE, you might need to augment your design with some additional runs.  See Minitab support note http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/modeling-statistics/doe/basics/f--and-p-values-that-are-shown-as-asterisks/

Typical successful Minitab regression output will show the P-values and standard deviation (as well as other statistics) in the ANOVA table and model summary as shown below:

```
Analysis of Variance

Source         DF   Adj SS    Adj MS  F-Value  P-Value
Regression      1  0.03728  0.037275   100.74    0.000
  Temperature   1  0.03728  0.037275   100.74    0.000
Error          98  0.03626  0.000370
  Lack-of-Fit  47  0.01698  0.000361     0.96    0.561
  Pure Error   51  0.01928  0.000378
Total          99  0.07354


Model Summary

        S    R-sq  R-sq(adj)  R-sq(pred)
0.0192354  50.69%     50.19%      48.55%


Coefficients

Term             Coef  SE Coef  T-Value  P-Value   VIF
Constant      100.234    0.022  4475.56    0.000
Temperature  -0.01073  0.00107   -10.04    0.000  1.00
```

Hope this is useful to you!